# Problems with character movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I changed my enemy path but after 1 try game display turned black, then I changed my enemy path back to normal but then my character wasn't able to move... It might be possibility that its something wrong with pygame or pycharm

I tried to press "Ctrl + z" multiple times, but it didin't work too.

My movement code:

```
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.walkCount = 0

    if not (man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10
        man.jumpCount = 10
```

Entire code you can see here:

Main: https://pastebin.com/pHgtUi5F

Player: https://pastebin.com/C4kmU2Rn

Projectile: https://pastebin.com/LgG5kCu3

Enemy: https://pastebin.com/wsgcbtUG

Comment: you should use `pygame.Rect()` to keep object size and position - it has function to check collisions between two or more `Rect()`

Comment: you can use `print()` to display which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. This way you may find where is the problem. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: you should use `pygame.display.update()` only in `redrawGameWindow` after you redraw all elements. Don't use it in other functions because it can make animation less smooth.

Comment: I put breakpoints and it doesnt react

Comment: then put breakpoints in other places to see which parts are executed. Then you can check why other parts are not executed. Maybe some if/else doesn't work in expected way. maybe you have wrong indentions and one `IF` is inside another `IF` but it shouldn't. In `main.py` I see that you have `if K_LEFT` is inside `if K_SPACE` so probably you can move only when you press `SPACE`.

Comment: Your `neg` is always equal to 1. Are your conditions properly indented?

Comment: I tried to move holding space and pressing space it doesn't work too... And I think my conditions are properly indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it started to work... So what I did was added the `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` in the main loop and I removed `if K_LEFT` , `if K_RIGHT` and etc... from the `if K_SPACE` so my walking code looks like this:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and shootLoop == 0:
    if man.left:
        facing = -1
    else:
        facing = 1

    if len(bullets) < 5:
        bullets.append(
            projectile(round(man.x + man.width // 2), round(man.y + man.height // 2), 6, (0, 0, 0), facing))
        shootLoop = 1

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
    man.x -= man.vel
    man.left = True
    man.right = False
    man.standing = False
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
    man.x += man.vel
    man.right = True
    man.left = False
    man.standing = False
else:
    man.standing = True
    man.walkCount = 0

if not (man.isJump):
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        man.isJump = True
        man.right = False
        man.left = False
        man.walkCount = 0
else:
    if man.jumpCount >= -10:
        neg = 1
        if man.jumpCount < 0:
            neg = -1
        man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
        man.jumpCount -= 1
    else:
        man.isJump = False
        man.jumpCount = 10
```